# Why can't I cast an Integer to a Long in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, casting

It seems this should be safe to do?

```
@Test
fun testCast() {
    val storeId : Any = Int.MAX_VALUE
    val numericStoreId = if(storeId is String) storeId.toLong() else storeId as Long
}
```

This yields:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long`

Why is Kotlin not allowing this? Our Kotlin version is 1.6.

The fix is writing `val numericStoreId = if(storeId is String) storeId.toLong() else (storeId as Number).toLong()` instead, but I don't get why it is required.

Comment: Please see [this answer](/a/61131112/10134209) on the difference between a _cast_ and a _conversion_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in Java either. They simply aren't the same types.

What you're trying to do is equivalent to this:

```java
Integer i = 0;
Long l = (Long) i;
```